# Symfony2 - change security entry point

Tags: rest, symfony, http-headers

Using symonfy as a REST API, I would like the server not to send such headers on a 401 :

```
 WWW-Authenticate : Basic realm=XXX
```

but something like

```
WWW-Authenticate : myOwnBasic realm=XXX
```

How can I overload the BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint class or make my own entry point class for basic auth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

You need to override this paramater in parameters.yml :

```
    security.authentication.basic_entry_point.class: NAMESAPCE\YOURCUSTOM_CLASS
```

And create a file where you prefer (I made it in MyBundle\Security\Http\EntryPoint) looking like :

```
<?php

namespace NAMESAPCE;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint;

class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint
{
    private $realmName;

    public function __construct($realmName)
    {
        $this->realmName = 'XXX';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('WWW-Authenticate', sprintf('myOwnBasic realm="%s"', $this->realmName));
        $response->setStatusCode(401);

        return $response;
    }
}
```